# Calculus generalized product rule and nth derivative problem

Tags: calculus

I need help answering these 2 questions. I was able to solve 8/1 but I have no idea how to proceed.

[image: Enter image description here[2]]

[image: Enter image description here[1]]

---

Here's my attempt for 8/1

Based on the product rule it should be: $f_1'(x)f_2(x) \cdots f_n(x)+f_1(x)f_2'(x) \cdots f_n(x)+ \cdots +f_1(x)f2(x) \cdots f_n'(x)$

Comment: The links somehow disappeared
http://i.stack.imgur.com/DNoAh.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/mSmwA.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide more details to this question, which include your own work and the difficulty you are facing in solving these questions.

Comment: Well really I just have no idea how to express (f1*f2)^(n) using higher derivatives of f1 and f2, I never faced a problem like this before

Comment: Kindly show us how you attempted 8/1 and we will see what we can do to help you.

Comment: Based on the product rule it should be: f1'(x)*f2(x)*.....fn(x)+f1(x)*f2'(x)*...*fn(x)+...+f1(x)*f2(x)*...*fn'(x)

Comment: Your 8.1 is true. Just to make thinks a bit formal you can do a simple proof by induction. Define $F_{n} = f_1f_2\ ... \ f_n$

Base case $n=2$ OK. Induction : $(f_1f_2\ ... \ f_n f_{n+1})' = (F_n f_{n+1})' = F_n' f_{n+1} + F_n f_{n+1}' = F_{n+1}'$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f^{(1)} = f'g + fg' \\
f^{(2)} = f''g + f'g' + f'g' + fg'' = f''g + 2f'g' + fg''\\
f^{(3)} = f'''g+f''g' +2(f''g' + f'g'') + f'g'' +fg''' = f'''g + 3f''g' + 3f' g'' + fg'''
$$
You see a pattern ? Think about $(x+y)^n$. [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: So I basically just write down the binomial theorem but instead of powers I write higher derivatives?

Comment: That's the idea. But of course, you should prove that this is indeed the right formula ;)

Comment: I suppose it won't be a problem using induction. Although I am not sure what is the recursive part, is it just simply that I express the (n-1)th derivative of f(x)?

Comment: Could you please help with the other problem as well? I know the funtions shape but have no idea what to do beyond that point